# How to send local push notification with react-native-onesignal

Tags: react-native

I want to send push notification to the user every day in a specific time, user location specific data with it.

I have been through the one signal documentation but didn't found anything specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onesignal does not serve local push notification. You can read the thread [here](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/126#issuecomment-273658358)

Though you can send locally using other libraries like [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#readme) or [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)